# Как с помощью rapidjson спарсить двумерный массив

Tags: c++, json, парсер, parse

Как считать, положить любые данные и записать снова вот этот  json формат с помощью rapidjson c++? В официальных примерах нет объяснения работы с двумерными массивами

```
{
    "angle_x_y": {
        "fg": [
            [1, 1]
        ],
        "ds": [
            [1, 1]
        ],
        "hold": [
            [1, 1]
        ],
        "number": 1
    }
}
```

Мой пример:

```
vector<int> detail = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
Document d;

Value angle_x_y(rapidjson::kObjectType);
Value fg(kArrayType);
Value ds(kArrayType);
Value step(kArrayType);
Value num;

Value detail_(kArrayType);
for (const auto &j : detail) {
    detail_.PushBack(j, d.GetAllocator());
    detail_.PushBack(j, d.GetAllocator());
}

fg.PushBack(detail_, d.GetAllocator());
ds.PushBack(detail_,d.GetAllocator());
hold.PushBack(detail_,d.GetAllocator());
num.SetInt(42);

angle_x_y.AddMember("fg", fg, d.GetAllocator());
angle_x_y.AddMember("ds", ds, d.GetAllocator());
angle_x_y.AddMember("hold", hold, d.GetAllocator());
angle_x_y.AddMember("number", num, d.GetAllocator());
```

Comment: Здесь нет двумерного массива. Есть одномерный, элементами которого являются другие одномерные массивы. Соответственно любого примера работы из интеренета для работы с одномерным массивам будет достаточно для реализации работы с этим.

Comment: @user7860670 а как мне в этот одномерный массив поместить ещё однин одномерный массив?

Comment: Эта операция ничем не отличается от добавления чисел в одномерный массив.

Comment: @user7860670 пробую ничего не получается

Comment: "ничего не получается" не является описанием проблемы. Составьте [mcve], в котором вы создаете json массив int, json массив с этим массивом и сам json документ, и опишите, что там не так. Тогда можно будет о чем-то говорить.

Comment: @user7860670 добавил в вопрос

Comment: Приведенный кусок кода не соответствует критериям, изложенным в статье [mcve]. Ну и никакого описания проблемы нет...